# vb.net looping through several passed parameters with same name

Tags: vb.net

i am passing paramters from one page to another all witht he same name...how do i look through them?

```
dim sHtmlBody
sHtmlBody = ""
for i=0 to Request.QueryString("name").Count

sHtmlBody = "<html><body onload=""window.print();"">"
sHtmlBody = sHtmlBody & "<body>hello</body>"
sHtmlBody = sHtmlBody & "</head>"

next

context.Response.Write(sHtmlBody)
```

this is what i am doing and it works. But how do i access the individual name

```
Dim Name =  Request.QueryString("Name")(i)
```

does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the request looks like this: `SomePage.aspx?name=name1&name=name2&name=name3` you could split the `Name` request parameter by comma:

```
Dim names = Request.QueryString("Name").Split(",")
For Each name As String In names
    ' do something with each name
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following.

```
dim sHtmlBody
sHtmlBody = ""
Dim nameValues As String = Request.Form.GetValues("name")

For Each name As var In nameValues

sHtmlBody = "<html><body onload=""window.print();"">"
sHtmlBody = sHtmlBody & "<body>hello</body>"
sHtmlBody = sHtmlBody & "</head>"

Next
```

Which means you can do the following.

```
Dim name = Request.Form.GetValues("name")(1)
```

Comment: Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: @Beginner at what point are u getting this errorr? the first code block the the single line code?